# Automatizar excel em sequencia em python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Em um formulario google que transforma todos os dados preenchidos em planilha excel, fiz em python uma programação que copia os dados da primeira linha e preenche um formulario que preciso.
Existe a possibilidade desse programa ler a linha debaixo e preencher um proximo formulario?

```
    Planilha formulario.xlsx 
    NOME   IDADE  
  0  Joao    40 
  1  Maria   30 
  2  José    20
```

```
import pandas as pd

formulario = pd.read_excel(r'C:\formulario.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')

nome, idade = formulario['NOME][0], str(formulario['IDADE'][0]

print(nome)
print(idade)
```

Hoje eu preciso toda vez executar o programa pra ele preencher com os dados da linha 0 do excel, e ao término, copiar a linha 1 pra zero e assim sucessivamente.
É possivel eu criar um input onde o programa antes de começar me pergunte de qual linha do excel eu quero buscar as informações?

Comment: Sim, existem inúmeras possibilidades. Você pode pesquisar sobre a função `input` do Python, por exemplo. Ou pesquisar como criar aplicações de linha de comando com Python.

Comment: veja loop 'for' em python